# New NextJS app return Error: Cannot find module 'C:\next\dist\bin\next' when yarn dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im using NodeJS version 16.15.0, I just tried to create a new NextJS app:

```
yarn create next-app --typescript
```

The follow the default options:

[image]

Then i just typed:

```
yarn dev
```

And got the following error:

```
$ next dev
/c/Dev/Mantis/newapp/node_modules/.bin/next: line 2: sed: command not found
/c/Dev/Mantis/newapp/node_modules/.bin/next: line 2: dirname: command not found
/c/Dev/Mantis/newapp/node_modules/.bin/next: line 4: uname: command not found
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\next\dist\bin\next'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

> Please help me! This has been struggling my head all weekend.

Comment: What is the name of the directory where you created your app? Does it happen to include any special characters (non-alphanumerical)?

Comment: Can you create a new project named MyApp isntead of my-app and see if that will help any?

Comment: I already did and i get the same error @Dimitar

Comment: @Dimitar this is the path: C:\Dev\Mantis\newapp

Comment: Do you have next installed globally? `npm install -g next`.
If you have, please try to uninstall it and re install it - `npm uninstall -g next && npm install -g next`. If it still doesn't work, try to remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` in your app folder. Let me know if any of these help.

Comment: Yes I did. I found a workaround to change the way it execute Nextjs server. But I think I'm dropping Nextjs, will just use React and Typescript because Nextjs is very slow and I didn't like how it behaves locally

Comment: Next JS can actually come in handy. It is a great tool that helps you do server-side rendering and SEO. You can use both React and TypeScript in combination with Next.